# Creating a relationship between unconnected tables

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, datamodel, star-schema

I've created two tables(pokemon,type)  which aren't connected but are filtered by the same dimension table(ID) using a many-to-one single direction connection. When I then tried to make a table chart consisting of  ID(ID table), type(type table),pokemon(pokemon table) it said that it couldn't determine a relationship between the two tables. I'm confused why this doesn't work because I've used the same approach with much larger and more complex data sets, and I've seen youtube videos do exactly the same thing. I'd like some help in getting to the bottom of this because I seem to missing some basic concept here.

I expected to be able to filter the pokemon and type tables by ID, to create a table chart despite there not being a connection between the two fact tables. Here is a link to a youtube video(skip to 6:50)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnyRsO4NJPc&t=81s
which shows that it is possible to filter multiple fact tables using dimension tables without the two fact tables themselves being linked.

HERE IS A LINK TO THE POWER BI FILE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13yKb8q3e-01-Vuo_LnWiSJjzy1zuAheP/view?usp=share_link

I've attached screenshots of the data model and the table chart that isn't currently working.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on `TYPE` in the visual Columns well and select First - then it will work. OR switch your relationships round so that ID is the Fact table...
[image]